# Firebase. Swift :Retrieve a message after 5 hours of the post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a messaging app in iOS that could have an option for user to delay sending message for a specific amount of time ( ex. Send this text 5 hours latter) and I am using Firebase as my database. Anyone know how to achieve this functionality?

Specifically:

Every time sending a message I use `Firebase.child(XXX).setValue(message)`
to add a new message into firebase

Then use
  `Firebase.child(XXX).observeEventType(.ChildAdded,...`
to get newly send message

Is there any way I could delay the `setValue` action for an amount of time and therefore achieve the functionality? Or there is better way to do it.

Comment: Please explain what you have already tried, and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like that in Firebase out of the box.

The easies solution for you here is to add filed like `validFrom` to your message and on client side to filter all messages by this field.

You can even add `validTo` field and make messages expire!

Comment: Thank you , That is one possible solution !  but client side need to be on, in order to get this message, which may be disable the offline push notification function?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not a good idea to delay setting a value to your Firebase Database, You can with **`Timer`** but then you have to be sure that your app has to be still in running mode five hours after you have started the **`Timer`**. Which i think even you understand is a stupid idea.

But what you can do is set your value to your Database with a timestamp as a key.

While setting the value :-

```
let timeStamp = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("your_path").setValue(["\(timeStamp)":"yourMessage"])
```

Where

- timeStamp    :- is your current timeStamp
- yourMessage  :- is your message

Whenever you wanna retrieve your message retrieve that message's timeStamp and check wether or not 5 hours have passed.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("your_path").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{(snap) in 

if let messageDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
   for each in messageDict{
     let timeKey = Int(each.0) //your TimeStamp
     let datePosted = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeKey))
     let elapsedTime_Hours = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince(datePosted as Date)/3600) 
     if elapsedTime_Hours >= 5 {
        print("Five hours have passed and now the user can see the message")
        } 
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ~ , but basically, I do not want to do it every time by a new piece of code, cause I really can't when client choose a random time to delay it's message.